# How to share a folder as NFS mount in windows 7 professional edition?

Tags: windows-7, nas, nfs

I need to share a folder as NFS mount for an application to pick the files up. My system is running in windows 7 professional edition. Is it possible to share a particular folder as NFS mount? If yes how to do it.

Comment: You may wish to investigate cygwin or winNFSd

Comment: There used to be support for setting up a nfs server in XP through  Windows Services for UNIX (SFU) (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/324089).  SFU was already deprecated when Win7 came out, but it was still included in some version. Unfortunately I have no Win7 install around to check,  but out of this support thread http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/nfs-client-for-windows-7/42aae25d-d077-4ff9-abdf-7314a589c46d, I make out it is only available for enterprise and ultimate. You probably have to resort to a third party tool like ssnobody suggest.

Comment: To people arriving here from Google who happen to be on Windows 10: Microsoft added NFS support to Windows 10 with the anniversary update.  Sadly, I couldn't find any documentation on it, but it's installable from the standard `Add or remove Windows components` dialog.  It probably exposes a `mount` command, just as its predecessors did.  I'm not sure if it offers a server, or how to use it, but there's a good chance it's in there somewhere.

Comment: I know you're +50 bounty is ending soon but you can check out: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/324089 and figure out where to download the Nfsshare.exe talked about there to configure for your use accordingly. If you find the tool, it's likely compatible with Windows 7 or has a version which is.

Comment: Sorry. It only applies to the following editions:
Microsoft Windows 2000 Server, Microsoft Windows 2000 Advanced Server, Microsoft Windows 2000 Professional Edition, Microsoft Windows XP Professional, Microsoft Windows NT 4.0 Service Pack 6a, Microsoft Windows NT Workstation 4.0 Developer Edition, Microsoft Windows Services for UNIX 3.0 Standard Edition

Comment: I just looked into this more and from what I see as listed here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753529(v=ws.11).aspx this is available on Windows Vista, Windows Server 2008, Windows Server 2012, Windows 8... So MS made something available on Vista and Windows 8 but not Windows 7... Well in any event as I've seen many times, just because Microsoft doesn't confirm something is not compatible with a specific OS and verify it worked in their labs does NOT mean it will absolutely not work... I'd do more reading and testing if it were me but that's just my suggestion...

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: use Hanewin NFS
http://www.sysprobs.com/configure-set-nfs-share-windows-7-ready-storage-vmware-esx

Option 2:

```
msiexec /I D:\sfusetup.msi /qb addlocal="NFSServer,NFSServerAuth" \ [targetdir="install path"]
```

then just right-click on folder -> share -> NFS
or

```
nfsshare -o anon=yes share_name=drive:path
```

Option 3:

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/nfs-client-for-windows-7/42aae25d-d077-4ff9-abdf-7314a589c46d

Comment: SFU is not available in Win 7 Pro, (which your option three link makes clear) and link only answers are discouraged. Also, option 3 discussed the NFS *client* rather than the server although neither will work on Professional edition. I believe Option 1 would work, but it would be better to reproduce the instructions from the link in your answer.

Comment: Indeed, it's 7 Pro, not enterprise. I didn't pay attention on it.

Answer (score -1):

If you mean sharing a folder over your LAN, then this should do: http://www.pcadvisor.co.uk/how-to/windows/how-share-folders-without-homegroups-in-windows-7-3434911/

Make sure to set the right permissions. Also, I'm pretty sure that this method requires the other computer to enter your credentials at least once, so if it's incapable of doing so (say, a very simple streamer), this may not work for you.

Comment: This does not use NFS at all.

Comment: @ssnobody Yes, but the description he gave was very simple, so I gave the simplest method, which will probably work. Note the NAS tag as well.

Comment: Perhaps it will work and perhaps not, but the question title and first sentence of the content are explicit in that the OP wants a NFS solution. Your answer is also a link only answer, which is discouraged.

Comment: Sounds to me like a specific application is being used that only supports NFS.